# Repeat multiple columns with random not-repeating rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have this code to repeat a column with names to three other columns, but the names are in the same row of the first one, as figure 1.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REPT(A2:A7&";";3);";"))
```

[image: figure 1]

I would like this formula to do new three columns randomly, in a way the names will be in different rows, not repeating them anytime at all, as figure 2.

[image: FIGURE 2]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
=QUERY({$A$1:$A$6, ARRAYFORMULA(RANDBETWEEN(0, 9^9+ROW($A$1:$A$6)))}, 
 "select Col1 order by Col2 limit 6", 0)
```

[image]

```
...pasted in B1 and dragged across to the D1
```

Comment: Player0, thanks for your help, but I would like an  item in column B2 different form A2 but also C2 different from B2 and A2; and D2 different form C2, B2 and A2. Is it possible?

Comment: @IvanSinigaglia yes, it's possible somehow... in meantime you can  try this non-random formula:
`=ARRAYFORMULA({SORT(SPLIT(REPT($A$1:$A$6&";",1),";"),1,0),
SPLIT(REPT({$A$6;$A$1;$A$4;$A$3;$A$2;$A$5}&";",1),";"),
SPLIT(REPT({$A$5;$A$3;$A$6;$A$2;$A$1;$A$4}&";",1),";")})`